# Is there a way to approximate a function as sum of Gaussian?

Tags: numerical-methods, normal-distribution, fourier-series, approximation, transformation

I'm a chemist, and my friend give me a spectroscopic data that was supposed to be sum of several Gaussian function $(G(x)=Ae^{-B(x-C)^2})$.

Let's say the data is given as function $f(x)$, is there a way to write 
$f(x)=\sum_{n}{}A_ne^{-B_n(x-C_n)^2}$ 
Just what we can do in Fourier series?

Comment: If you hear about "radial basis functions", this is most likely one variant. This type of kernel is widely used to find empirical forms of a sampled function, something like a continuous histogram, and is also the second example for alternative kernels in support-vector machines (SVM). This is largely non-linear regression, so not a nice transform like the FFT.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate Lutz Lehmann's comment, you can do kernel regression using the Gaussian kernel function.

**General Flow**

We use matrix notation $\mathbf{f}=\mathbf{K}\mathbf{A}$ for conciseness:

$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
f\left(x_{1}\right) \\
f\left(x_{2}\right) \\
\vdots \\
f\left(x_{n}\right) 
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-B_{1}\left(x_{1}-C_{1}\right)^{2}} &
e^{-B_{2}\left(x_{1}-C_{2}\right)^{2}} &
\cdots &
e^{-B_{n}\left(x_{1}-C_{n}\right)^{2}} \\
e^{-B_{1}\left(x_{2}-C_{1}\right)^{2}} &
e^{-B_{2}\left(x_{2}-C_{2}\right)^{2}} &
\cdots &
e^{-B_{n}\left(x_{2}-C_{n}\right)^{2}} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
e^{-B_{1}\left(x_{n}-C_{1}\right)^{2}} &
e^{-B_{2}\left(x_{n}-C_{2}\right)^{2}} &
\cdots &
e^{-B_{n}\left(x_{n}-C_{n}\right)^{2}} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
A_{1} \\
A_{2} \\
\vdots \\
A_{n}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

The coefficients $A_{i}$s are obtained by solving the system of linear equations, typically using pseudo - inverse.

**Caveat**

While $A_{i}$s are obtained from solving the system of equations, you are the one who needs to choose (or tune) the coefficients $B_{i}$s and $C_{i}$s yourself. Some really rough guides:

- The smaller $B_{i}$s are, the smoother your approximation will be.
- Typically people use $C_{i}=x_{i}$ so the matrix $\mathbf{K}$ will have larger values on its diagonal which will stabilize the matrix solver